# MYSQL Issue in fetching profit data from multiple table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 3 MYSQL Tables `User` table and 2 `Transactions` table.

My User table is as follows.

```
id     inviter_id    active .... (other columns)
2      1             1
3      1             1
4      2             1
5      1             1
6      2             1
```

My txn1 table is

```
id     payer_id     receiver_id     amount     type
1      2            1               20         profit
2      3            1               30         profit
3      4            2               20         profit
4      3            2               50         profit
5      5            2               20         profit
```

My txn2 table is

```
id     payer_id     receiver_id     amount     txn_type
1      2            1               20         profit
2      3            2               30         profit
3      4            2               20         profit
4      3            1               50         profit
5      5            1               20         profit
```

What I need to get is,
Consider I'm querying for the user `2`. I need the profit he has earned from each of his downline or referrals using the `inviter_id` column.

For example, If I want to get the profit of User #2 from Txn1 and Txn2 table, it should get the txns made by user 4 and user 6 in txn1 and txn2 tables.

What I have tried so far is,

```
$userID = 2;
$this->db->select('u.id as partner_id, SUM(txn1_profit.amount) AS t1Profit, SUM(txn2_profit.amount) AS t2Profit');
$this->db->from('users u');
$this->db->join('txn1 txn1_profit', "u.id = txn1_profit.payer_id AND $userID = txn1_profit.receiver_id AND 'profit' = txn1_profit.txn_type",'LEFT');
$this->db->join('txn2 txn2_profit', "u.id = txn2_profit.payer_id AND $userID = txn2_profit.receiver_id AND 'profit' = txn2_profit.txn_type",'LEFT');
        
        $this->db->where('u.inviter_id', $userID);      
        $this->db->group_by('u.id');

        $query = $this->db->get(); 
        $row = $query->result();
        
        if (empty($row))
            return FALSE;
        return $row;
```

The problem with this query is i'm getting a huge sum value.

Comment: 'it should get the txns made by user 4 and user 6 in txn1 and txn2 tables.' there is no column called user in these tables - you need to clarify the relationships between these tables and do add desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If schema of your transaction tables is same then I would suggest you to change your schema and have one single transaction table to store such information. By changing your current design will help you to build simple queries may reduce no. of joins.

For your current schema I can think of 2 possible ways to address your profit value issue.

Calculate sum from your transaction tables in sub-clause and then do a join with users table

```
select u.inviter_id, 
       sum(t1.t1Profit), 
       sum(t2.t2Profit),
       sum(t1.t1Profit) + sum(t2.t2Profit) total
from users u
left join (
  select payer_id, sum(amount) t1Profit
  from tx1
  where 2 = receiver_id 
  and 'profit' = type
  group by payer_id
) t1 on u.id = t1.payer_id
left join (
  select payer_id, sum(amount) t2Profit
  from tx2
  where 2 = receiver_id 
  and 'profit' = txn_type
  group by payer_id
) t2  on u.id = t2.payer_id
where u.inviter_id = 2;
```

Or combine data of your transaction tables using `union all` and then do a join with users table

```
select u.inviter_id, 
       sum(t1.amount) total
from users u
left join (
  select payer_id, amount
  from tx1
  where 2 = receiver_id 
  and 'profit' = type
  union all 
  select payer_id, amount
  from tx2
  where 2 = receiver_id 
  and 'profit' = txn_type
) t1 on u.id = t1.payer_id
where u.inviter_id = 2;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0df606/10)

Comment: Modified your code according to CI's code and it all worked very well. Used the first method.